# How does "chrome.tabs.getSelected" work?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This is code:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (abcd) {
        alert(abcd.index));
        });
```

I wonder know how this tab object 'abcd' is transfered to callback function from parent 'getSelected' method?

Where is this 'abcd' generate from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood correctly, `getSelected()` function might look like this
(the names of underlying functions are fictional)

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected = function(windowId, callback) {
    var selectedTab = GET_SELECTED_TAB(windowId || CURRENT_WINDOW_ID);
    callback(selectedTab); // this calls your function with the tab object as a parameter (abcd = selectedTab)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I find it looks like `Proc.call` in ruby.

Comment: Exactly. You can also use explicit call: `callback.call(null, selectedTab)`